# How to load JSON data into Hive table?

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, flume

I have JSON data of tweets. I'm getting this data using flume & loading it into hive for further analysis. I have load the data into hive using normal load command, also added JSON serde library `hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` This is my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `tweets`(
  `id` bigint, 
  `text` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
```

while doing : `select * from tweets;`
I am getting this error:

> Failed with exception
>   java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException:
>   org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('O'
>   (code 79)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object,
>   'true', 'false' or 'null')

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the question? Also, you should use the formatting option to make this readable!

Comment: I just edit my question

Comment: Hi make id  string

Comment: made id string , still not working giving same error;

Comment: @jayesh_mahajan: do you have a sample of your JSON data?

Comment: @jayesh_mahajan: could you please show us sample JSON. This post is old, i hope the issue is resolved. if yes could you post the answer to this?